# pythonでリストで最初の方に文字列があるときにその部分を削除したい

Tags: python, python3

python3.5を使っています。例えば["a","b",1,2,3]というリストがあったときに、[1,2,3]というリストに直したいです。下は、試しに書いてみたコードです。

```
list1=["a","b",1,2,3]


list_number=False
while list_number==True:
    try:
        float(list1[0])
        list_number=True
    except:
        list1=list1[1:]
        list_number=False

print(list1)
```

これでlist1が[1,2,3]に変換されると思ったのですが、変わりませんでした。どうすればよいのでしょうか。

Comment: 言い換えると「(元のリストは)数字の要素だけが含まれた状態にしたい」という事でしょうか。

Comment: 質問の意図からは少しずれますが、その方が汎用性があって望ましいですね。

Comment: 現在扱っているCSVファイルを取り込むと、最初の方に文字列が入ってしまうのでその部分を削除したいというのが元々のモチベーションです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list1=["a","b",1,2,3]
```

として、要件を満たす最も簡潔な方法は、下記のような記述でしょう。

```
[x for x in list1 if type(x) is not str] #=>[1,2,3]
```

各要素のうち、文字列型でないものを抽出できます。
他の言語においてはfilterとか言われているリスト操作ですが、pythonでは上記のようにリスト内包表記にifを用いることでフィルタリングを簡単に実行できます。
またpythonは値自体が型をもっているのでそれ(str型)を利用したほうが、floatにキャストして例外処理を行うよりも好ましいと思います。

Comment: こんな便利な書き方があったんですね。回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

ご自身の修正ですと、要素が**全て数値以外**の場合に無限ループに陥るため、ご注意ください。

数字が出るまで先頭の要素を消すコードと、数字以外の要素を除外するコードの例を記載します。

```
#数字が出るまで先頭の要素を消す
list1 = ["a","b",1,2,3,"c",0.5]
for v in list1:
    try:
        float(v)
        break   #数字が出てきた時点でループ終了
    except:
        list1 = list1[1:]

print(list1) #数字がない場合空要素[]になる

#数字以外の要素を除外する
def is_num(s):
    try:
        float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

list2 = ["a","b",1,2,3,"c",0.5]
list2 = [f for f in list2 if is_num(f)]
print(list2)
```

Comment: 詳しい回答ありがとうございます。数字のみを抽出する方法も教えていただき、感激です。

Answer (score 0):

```
while list_number==True
```

を

```
while list_number==False
```

にしたら出来ました。